# React-Native; Objects are not valid as a react child

Tags: react-native, fetch

I'm getting an error at `dataSource: responseJson.event_array`, when I remove this line everything works fine however, when I compare it to other peoples code it's the same. It does reach the server, because I do not get the alert message.

```
 componentDidMount() {    
            fetch('valid url')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    dataSource: responseJson.event_array,
                    isLoading: false
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert('Could not reach the server!')
            });
        }
```

What am I doing wrong, The error is

> Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found:
> object with keys {_40,_65,_55,_72})

'valid url' points to a json file and is indeed an object, I'm trying to use the data to compare it to other data stored to use a if function which will decide whether the item of FlatList will be rendered or not

```
<FlatList
                data={this.state.dataSource}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                keyExtractor={item => item.name}
            />
```

another piece of code

```
renderItem = async ({item}) => {
        var approved = false;

        var name_string = await AsyncStorage.getItem('planner_name');

        if(name_string != null){
            var name_array = name_string.split(',');

            name_array.map(name => {
                if(name == item.name){
                    approved = true;
                }
            })
        }


startReading = ({item}) => {
    this.setState({
        reading: true,
        item: item
    });
}
        if(approved){
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 5}} onPress={() => this.startReading({item})}>
                    <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }
```

If you have any question feel free to ask.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'd suspect, without any other context, that the `event_array` is actually an object and your render function is trying to render it.  FYI: Using propTypes could help catch errors like this.

Comment: 'valid url' points to a json file and is indeed an object, I'm trying to use the data to compare it to other data stored to use a if function wich will decide wether the item of FlatList will be rendered or not

Comment: The error is telling you it can't render an object.  You're possibly storing an object as your source, and react's flatlist is expecting an array [source](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#data).  Try a console.log of the `responseJson` to see what you're storing, or post that response with your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

> object with keys {_40,_65,_55,_72}

is an unresolved promise. I suspect the issue is that `this.renderItem` is an `async` function which I suspect is not allowed. `async` is essentially going to wrap the result of your function in a `Promise`, which then must be resolved. Since `renderItem` does not expect a `Promise`, it does not know to resolve one and as such is simply returning an unresolved `Promise` object for each item in your data source.

Instead you could try using an `async` function expression:

```
renderItem = ({item}) => {
  const get_name_string = async function(key){
    const name_string = await AsyncStorage.getItem('key')
    return name_string
  }
  get_name_string('planner_name').then(name => {
    // the rest of your renderItem function should be in this block
  })
}
```

or simply using `.then` syntax on the call to `AsyncStorage`

```
renderItem = ({item}) => {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('planner_name').then(name => {
  // again, the rest of your function should be in this block
  })
}
```

or better yet find another pattern that doesn't require you to use asynchronous code in your `renderItem` function. Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions!