# Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72})

Tags: javascript, react-native, location, expo

I have one Flatlist and in flat list each item has geolocation.

I am calling `{this.getitemlocation(item.location)}` from inside of `Flatlist`. Here `getitemlocation()` is function and `item.location` is longitude and latitude.

My `getitemlocation()`:

```
 async getitemlocation(item) {
   let locationstring = item.split(",");
    if(locationstring[0]!="None"&&locationstring[1]!="None"){
    let location = {
      latitude: Number(locationstring[0]),
      longitude: Number(locationstring[1]),
    };
    itemloacation = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(location);
    return (
      <Text style={styles.itemLocation} key={item}>
        {itemloacation.name} {"\u2022"} 2.3 km
      </Text>
    );
    }
    else{
      return (
        <Text style={styles.itemLocation}>
          No Location
        </Text>
      );
    }
  }
```

Error I am getting:

> Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: It seems like you have to resolve the promise because your function is async.

Comment: @yesIamFaded how should I do it?

Comment: Hm what does reverseGeocodeAsync do maybe show the code too also do you know where exactly the error shows when you do what.

Comment: @yesIamFaded  reverseGeocodeAsync converts longitude and latitude to city and country, its a inbuilt function in expo, when I remove async and await the error is goes but then it does not get the location.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53325386/react-native-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child - take a look here your problem will be similar basically you are missing a .then() where you get the value and a .catch() at the end where you can handle an error if it occurs.

Comment: @yesIamFaded That does not work for me, when I used that solution, nothing displayed in my list.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return on async function like that. You can use Promise like this:

```js
getitemlocation(item){
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    let locationstring = item.split(",");
    if(locationstring[0]!="None"&&locationstring[1]!="None"){
      let location = {
        latitude: Number(locationstring[0]),
        longitude: Number(locationstring[1]),
      };
      itemloacation = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(location);
      resolve(
        <Text style={styles.itemLocation} key={item}>
          {itemloacation.name} {"\u2022"} 2.3 km
        </Text>
      )
    }else{
      resolve (
        <Text style={styles.itemLocation}>
          No Location
        </Text>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: When you get data, you call: let text_location = await this.getitemlocation(item)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not work for me, getting same error. Any thing else I can try?

Comment: No no. You must using await when you get return from getitemlocation