# AsyncStorage getitem giving error in useEffect in React Native

Tags: react-native, jwt, token, asyncstorage

AsyncStorage.getItem is giving this error in react native when added in useEffect what am I doing wrong here can anyone pls help me understand the error.

```
export default function Pregent_login(props) {
  const [first, setfirst] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('route.params ==>', props.route.params);

     const value = AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
     setfirst(value);
  }, []);
```

[image: simulatore screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the below code:

```
export default function Pregent_login(props) {
  const [first, setfirst] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('route.params ==>', props.route.params);

      AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then(token => {
        setfirst(token);
      })
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try using this way

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then(token => {
  // again, the rest of your function should be in this block
})
```

More details [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53325386/react-native-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child)